# Find a compactification $K(X)$ for the indicated space $X$ as required. Let $E(X)$ denote the remainder, so $E(X) = K(X) - X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactification

I am having difficulty dealing with the problem below. The problem is from Munkrees Topology text. Can someone please help me solving the problem? 
$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$

Find a compactification $K(X)$ for the indicated space $X$ as required. Let $E(X)$ denote the  remainder, so $E(X) = K(X) - X$.

(b) $X=\N$ and $E(X)$ consists of exactly three isolated points.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Let us use the three disjoint infinite subsets $N_1,N_2,N_3$ of $\Bbb N$ and add $p_1,p_2,p_3$ as new points to $\Bbb N$ and use cofinite subsets of $N_i$ plus $\{p_i\}$ as a local base at $p_i$, generalising the one-point compactification idea. Disjointness is needed for Hausdorffness of the resulting space.

(c) $X=\N$ and $E(X)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Suppose $X=([0,1] \times \{0\}) \cup \{(q_n, \frac{1}{n+1}): n \in \omega\}$ where $q_n, n \in \omega$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, as a subspace of the plane. The scattered points above the interval are discrete, so homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$, and $X$ is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For c) try $X=([0,1] \times \{0\}) \cup \{(q_n, \frac{1}{n+1}): n \in \omega\}$ where $q_n, n \in \omega$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, as a subspace of the plane. The scattered points above the interval are discrete, so homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$, and $X$ is compact.

For b) use the three disjoint infinite subsets $N_1,N_2,N_3$ of $\Bbb N$ and add $p_1,p_2,p_3$ as new points to $\Bbb N$ and use cofinite subsets of $N_i$ plus $\{p_i\}$ as a local base at $p_i$, generalising the one-point compactification idea. Disjointness is needed for Hausdorffness of the resulting space.

For a) I have some ideas, but please think for yourself first..

Fun fact: for $\Bbb R$ the remainder can only be finite if it has 1 or 2 points.

Comment: I believe I figured out (a). Do you agree with it? I posted it above. Also, can you expound what you mean by cofinite subsets of $N_i$, please? Thanks!

Comment: @brucemcmc Maybe (a) works, not sure yet. Your base is unclear! You should also post a proof that it is a compact Hausdorff space, that's part of the solution. A cofinite subset of $N_i$ is a subset that misses at most finitely many points of $N_i$. You should provide  a check yourself the new space is Hausdorff, not just copy the claim.

Comment: Yes, I am still thinking about how to delineate what is occurring in (b); the definition of cofinite does help, thank you. And I agree with (c) and understand it well. Thank you for the feedback. I will adjust my (a).